# Passing literals to pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, literals

Is there a way to  pass a literal value  to a function argument of a pointer .

eg

```
 unsigned char returnBitShift(unsigned char* bit , unsignedChar* shiftBitsToRight){ 
    return (*bit) >> (*shiftBitsToRight);
}
unsigned char someBit = 254 , bitval;
bitVal = returnBitShift(&someBit,(unsigned char)& 1);
```

Comment: what kind of literal? what are you trying to do?

Comment: 1. It seems pointless for such a function to take pointers as arguments. 2. It seems pointless for this to be a function.

Comment: Suggestion for improvements?

Comment: Unless you are working on a microcontroller without an operating system (a freestanding environment), your code is not valid C. Even then, `(unsigned char)& 1` makes no sense.

Comment: Umm...how do i make it valid (new to c)? , so would i have  to something like this then , const unsigned char bitMask = 1; ,  then pass that in the function as a substitute to the literal of 1  , eg &bitMask?

Comment: Did you write the function `returnBitShift`?  If so, rewrite it to not use pointers.  If someone else wrote it and you have to use it as is, then either use a temporary variable as you suggested, or a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) that's an array of length 1.

Comment: And if it really just does a shift, then don't use it at all, and just replace the whole thing with `bitval = someBit >> 1;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a compound literal to create an unnamed object, and its address can be taken and passed to a function:

```
bitval = returnBitShift(&someBit, & (unsigned char) {1});
```

A compound literal is form with a type in parentheses followed by an initializer list in braces.

Comment: Gets error on compound literal , expression must have integral type?

Comment: @binaryOps20: The code in my answer is correct standard C except that `somebit` should have been `someBit`, and the `unsignedChar` in your `returnBitShift` should be `unsigned char`, I presume. If you still get the error, you should show the full error message, the line it is referring to, and state the compiler name and version you are using.

Comment: Changed to  ANSI C , instead of visual studio , in project settings ,  that was causing  the issue  funily enough